# Camel-Mongo connection with authentication not working

Tags: spring, mongodb, apache-camel

I am using camel to connect to MongoDB. It works fine without authentication ON MongoDB. But when I run with **--auth** and try connecting it does not insert a document into the collection. Manually from command prompt, it does.

Endpoint:

```
from("timer://myTimer?period=6000000").setBody()
    .simple(jsonString)
    .to("mongodb:myDb?database=customerdb&collection=customer&operation=insert");
```

and application-context.xml has entry like

```
<bean id="myDB" class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
<constructor-arg index="0">
    <bean class="com.mongodb.MongoURI">
        <constructor-arg index="0" 
        value="mongodb://$mongodb{user}:$mongodb{passwd}@$mongodb{host}:$mongodb{port}/$mongodb{db}">
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</constructor-arg>

org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.CamelMongoDbException: 
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { 
 "serverUsed" : "redacted" , 
 "errmsg" : "need to login" , 
 "ok" : 0.0}
```

Comment: what is this `$mongodb{user}`

Comment: I mean where is this value coming from? from application.properties file?

Comment: @pvpkiran : i can share code with you..you can just directly run CamelMongoRun..Please find code from link https://www.dropbox.com/s/nfq3k1ufyqvdtnj/mongo-test-camel.zip?dl=0

Comment: @pvpkiran I am hardcoding value as of now.. I am really stuck if you can help.. It will be really good.. JUST to add if i dont run with --auth, it gets stored in db.

Comment: when you hardoce the value does it work or no?

Comment: Yes..please help me how can we chat? can you share your gmail address..it did not work.. I have shared my sample code.

Comment: @pvpkiran I am new here and dont have enough reputations to talk here..but need help if you can

Comment: let  me check your project

Comment: @pvpkiran I hope you are clear with my problem